# How to sort a list according to the parity of the index of an item in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

For example, I have:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

I want to create a function (a key) such that:

```
def myfunc(a_list_of_items):
    # I have no idea what to do after this

a.sort(key=myfunc)
print(a)
```

Output should be:

```
["a","c","b","d"] #elements that had odd index -
# - stacked at one side and those with even stacked on the other
```

Comment: May be you are looking for this `result = sorted(a, key=lambda x: a.index(x) % 2)`

Comment: One way to do this would be to get the odd and even index separately and append one to the other

Comment: Which kind of parity?

Comment: parity as in the even or oddness of the element's index.

Comment: In this case, `a[0::2] + a[1::2]` will work, you don't need to sort.

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM That would definitely fail if an entry appears multiple times though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following (uses [Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)):

```
a[::2] + a[1::2]
```

This will result in:

```
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
```

Here, the `sorted()` function is not very appropriate in my opinion.

Comment: I wonder how `sorted` handles a list resulting from interleaving two sorted lists. I know it's optimized to handle lists with long sorted runs.

Answer (score 0):

I <strike>would</strike> might use

```
[x for (_, x) in sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda i: i[0] % 2)]
```

First, `enumerate` creates a list of index/value pairs from the original list. The given `key` function extracts the index and finds the remainder *modulo* 2; even indices are 0 and odd indices are 1, so that is sufficient to get the order you want. The list comprehension then extracts the original values from the sorted list of index/value pairs.

(For the given problem, concatenating two slices is certainly simpler, although possibly more costly. Benchmarking would determine which of the two approaches is faster/more efficient.)

Comment: I've ran a quick benchmark using `a = [1, 2, 3] * 100000` (the list only has 300000 elements) with `timeit("a[::2] + a[1::2]", "from __main__ import a", number=10)` and `timeit("[x for (_, x) in sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda i: i[0] % 2)]", "from __main__ import a", number=10)` and the results were already pretty clear. The slicing approach consistently does it in about `0.035...` while this one in about `1.4...` seconds. Seems like Python's slicing is pretty efficient.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't worried about the slicing, but the `+` operation to build the result. However, I overlooked that this is just *one* `+`, not a series of them to build up the result one element at a time.